# Show that $f(x) = d(x,x_0)$ is continuous using the topological definition

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Given $f : X \to Y$ such that $f(x) = d(x,z)$ for some constant $z \in X$ show that $f$ is continuous using the topological definition. (I can prove it in other ways)

I think one should proceed by taking the open set $U \subset Y$ and then show that for every $u \in U$, there is an open neighborhood of $f^{-1}(u)$ that is in $f^{-1}(U)$. This eventually shows that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.

How do I find that open neighborhood?

Comment: What is $d$? ${}{}$

Comment: An arbitrary metric.

Comment: Ok so $Y$ is just $\mathbb R$ right?

Comment: If $d$ is a metric, $Y$ should be $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It could be a subset, but since they essentially mean the same, yes.

Comment: Do you know what the open sets are in the metric space $X$? That's going to be crucial for this question.

Comment: @GregMartin I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = d(x,a)$. $B[a,s] = \{ x : d(x,a) \leq s \}$.
For all $r,s \in \mathbb{R}$ and the base set $(r,s)$,
$f^{-1} (r,s) = { x : r < f(x) < s } =  
(X - B[a,r]) \cap B(a,s)$ is open.